# memory corrupt using assembler procedure

Tags: c, assembly, x86

I've written this procedure in asm:

```
    .586
    .model flat, stdcall
    .xmm
    .data
    .code
    EncryptAsm proc plainText:ptr byte, heigth:DWORD, inputLength:DWORD,  encryptedText:ptr byte, cipherArray:ptr byte

local   addRow:WORD
local   row:DWORD 
local   column:DWORD 
local   iterator:DWORD 
local   forLoopIteratorI:DWORD
local   forLoopIteratorJ:DWORD




push    esi
push    edi
push    ebx
push    ecx
push    edx

mov     addRow,0
mov     row,0
mov     column,0
mov     iterator,0
mov     forLoopIteratorI,0
mov     forLoopIteratorJ,0


mov     ecx,heigth




FILL_CIPHER_ARRAY_LOOP: mov eax, inputLength
                        cmp iterator,eax
                        jge PREPARE_ITERATOR


                        push ecx ;pushing heigth value
                        mov ecx,row ;calculating index of cipher array   index=[row*inputLength+column]
                        imul ecx,inputLength
                        add ecx,column

                        mov eax,iterator



                        mov edx,plainText
                        mov al,[edx+eax]
                        mov [esi],al

                        mov ebx, cipherArray
                        mov [ebx+ecx],al

                        movsb



                        pop ecx;getting back heigth value


                        add column,1
                        cmp addRow,0
                        je INC_ROW
                        cmp addRow,0
                        jne DEC_ROW

                        INC_ROW:            add row,1
                                            jmp ROW_COMPARE

                        DEC_ROW:            sub row,1
                                            jmp ROW_COMPARE

                        ROW_COMPARE:        cmp row,ecx
                                            jge IF_STATEMENT_1
                                            cmp row,0
                                            jl IF_STATEMENT_2
                                            jmp INCREMENT_ITERATOR


                        IF_STATEMENT_1:     sub row,2
                                                mov addRow,1
                                            jmp INCREMENT_ITERATOR

                        IF_STATEMENT_2:     add row,2
                                            mov addRow,0
                                            jmp INCREMENT_ITERATOR
                        INCREMENT_ITERATOR: add iterator,1
                                            jmp FILL_CIPHER_ARRAY_LOOP


PREPARE_ITERATOR:       mov iterator,0


READ_CIPHER_ARRY_LOOP_I:cmp forLoopIteratorI,ecx
                        jge PREPARE_ITERATOR_2

READ_CIPHER_ARRY_LOOP_J:mov eax, inputLength
                        cmp forLoopIteratorJ,eax
                        jge PREPARE_I_AND_J
                        push ecx ;pushing heigth value
                        mov ecx,forLoopIteratorI ;calculating index of cipher array
                        imul ecx,inputLength
                        add ecx,forLoopIteratorJ
                        mov ebx,cipherArray
                        mov al,[ebx+ecx]
                        cmp al,'#'
                        jne COPY_VALUE
                        ITERATE:            add forLoopIteratorJ,1
                                            pop ecx
                                            jmp READ_CIPHER_ARRY_LOOP_J

PREPARE_I_AND_J:        mov forLoopIteratorJ,0
                        add forLoopIteratorI,1
                        jmp READ_CIPHER_ARRY_LOOP_I

COPY_VALUE:             push edi
                        mov edi,iterator
                        mov edx,encryptedText
                        mov [edx+edi],al
                        add iterator,1
                        pop edi
                        jmp ITERATE

PREPARE_ITERATOR_2:     mov iterator,0


FINISH:                 mov eax, encryptedText
                        pop     edx
                        pop     ecx
                        pop     ebx
                        pop     edi
                        pop     esi
                        ret

   EncryptAsm endp
    end
```

It implements rail fence cipher algorithm (at the end the variable encryptedText contains ciphered plainText). It works fine, I mean it does the encryption well but after all I'm getting memory corrupt error... I'm calling this procedure as an extern one from C app. I can print the encrypted text without any problem but when returning 0 in main function, the memory corrupt error pops up.

I don't know what can cause it. At the beginning of asm procedure, I push all the registers' values and pop them after the whole operation.

The error message:
`Unhandled exception at 0x72676F74 in ConsoleApplication12.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation executing location 0x72676F74.`

I'll be greatful for any hint.

Comment: You overwrite some memory buffers?

Comment: Debugger. Single Step. Register Window. Look for buffer writes.

Comment: @Joachim Pileborg  Probably yes, but I can't find the cause. As I wrote, I pop every value back at the end of the procedure.

Comment: It's not about the register, but the memory you write to in the code. Check loop conditions to make sure the are okay, and as mah says, single-step through the code while checking register and variables and everything else.

Comment: You should focus on the boundaries of your algorithm as well as on the instructions like `edx+edi` and others. Maybe your indexes are out of bounds.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

People I've found it! The cause of the error was... 'movsb'. I was using it in a previous version of my algorithm and I've forgotten to delete it... The rest of my code works fine. Thanks for all the answers and for willing to help m ;)

Answer (score 1):

One possible candidate could be here:

```
mov edx,plainText
mov al,[edx+eax]
mov [esi],al
```

`esi` is pushed, from the caller, but where is it initialized? It seems that it uses whatever is there from the caller. Same for `edi` so where will `movsb` store it?

**UPDATE**

Since I don't know your algorithm and don't see how it is used I can only guess. BUt I think you should do the following before the loop:

```
mov esi, plainText
mov edi, encryptedText
mov ebx, cipherArray
```

Since you don't change these values you can then change this code:

```
COPY_VALUE:         push edi
                    mov edi,iterator
                    mov edx,encryptedText
                    mov [edx+edi],al
                    add iterator,1
                    pop edi
                    jmp ITERATE
```

to this:

```
COPY_VALUE:         mov edx,iterator
                    mov [edx+edi],al
                    inc iterator
                    jmp ITERATE
```

Generally instead of using `add x, 1`  you can use `inc x` which is shorter.

Comment: should I do mov esi,0 or something?

Comment: No, because this would be a NULL pointer. YOui must initilize it with some value which would be appropriate. i.E. probably your target buffer for `edi` and the source for `esi` I assume. I haven't looked into the algorithm and how it works, just looked if I can spot some obvious problems.

Comment: I would i.e. initliaze `plaintext` for `esi`, `encryptedText` for `edi` and `cipherArray` in `ebx`. From the looks of your implementation it is sufficient so you have `eax, ecx and edx` free to use and you can do away with loading it during the algorithm. Should make it clearer to understand and more efficient as well, since you don't appear to change it but seem to load `ebx` with the same value again and again, whcih is just noise in your code.